# MySQL, PHP - search engine on dynamic product features (in another table)

Tags: php, mysql, pivot

**my objective: display products which have some features (determined by a form)**

my data structure simplified (if it appear to be bad, feel free to tell me):
table products

- id
- name (eg: shoe)

table product_features

- product_id
- type (eg: size)
- value (eg: 42)

My question: How can I SELECT the list of products which got the feature'stype "size" and the value "42" and "43"

a product can have many "product_features", even with a same type
  (eg: color->red, size->42, size->43)

a sample of what I try:

- LEFT JOIN ON product_features as many time I've got a product_features for each product (very heavy)
- create a vue with a pivot -> structure problem when a product got many product_features with same type (eg: many size)
- do it in php -> can't get every product_features without very heavy process

(I'm french, so, sorry for my poor english)
Thank A LOT in advance

Comment: You should post the query you're currently using.

Answer (score 0):

i think it's just a simple INNER JOIN that 'll get your results then HAVING COUNT(f.value) = 2 will make sure that that product has size 42 and 43.

```
SELECT p.id,p.name
FROM product_features f
INNER JOIN products p ON p.id = f.product_id
WHERE f.type = 'size' AND f.value IN ('42','43')
GROUP BY p.id,p.name
HAVING COUNT(f.value) = 2
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eda53/3

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this:

```
SELECT `products`.*, `product_features`.* FROM `products`
LEFT JOIN `product_features` as `product_features`
ON `product_features`.product_id = `products`.id

#has and is in size 
JOIN `product_features` as `pf`
ON `pf`.`product_id` = `products`.`id`
AND `pf`.`type` = "size"
AND `pf`.`value` IN ('42','43');
```

Because We're using regular old `JOIN`'s, we should exclude any products that

1. Don't have any attributes
2. Don't have a size attribute with a value of 42 or 43.